# Pass Value Selected From a User Control to a Parent

Tags: c#, winforms, events, user-controls, delegates

I have a Winform dialog that contains several user controls - all of them are some sort of `Datagridview`. The main parent has details about a user, and the user controls each have additional details on that person. When my Dialog first loads all of the UserControls work but I am trying to figure out how to update the UserControl2 based on a position change in UserControl1.

So, I am trying to select a row in UserControl1 and have the data in UserControl2 update based on a value that I just selected.

I have tried using `MouseDownEvents` on the UserControl1 and `BindingSourcePositionChanged` but I can't figure out how to get the value selected back to my parent form and then use that value to refresh the other datagrids?

I looked at [delegates and events](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/lesson14.aspx) but I guess the lack of sleep is making it incredibly hard to comprehend.  I understand that I need to create my delegate and event on the UserControl1 and then somehow call it on my mainform but that's where I get stuck and have no clue where to start.

Is this the right direction?  Or is there another way to get this done?  Can anyone offer up any suggestions on how this works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is the correct approach something like the following will provide an event handler that you can use to the retrieve a public property from the UserControl:

```
public class SomeClass : BaseControl
{
    public event EventHandler PersonSelected;

    public string Name{get;set;}

    protected void FindUser()
    {
        var find = new Button {ID = (ToString() + "search"), Text = "Search"};
            find.Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
                              {
                                  if (PersonSelected!= null)
                                  {
                                      //forward this event to the page's event handler
                                      PersonSelected(this, e);
                                  }
                              }; 
     }
}

public class SomeOtherClass : Page
{
    public void Main()
    {

       var sp = (SomeClass)Control;
                        sp.PersonSelected += BtnClick;
     }

    public void BtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Get some value from the (SomeClass)Control here
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that help a lot. Raising an event to the parent form can handle it is the way to go!